# How to implement two queries within one MySQL statement?

Tags: php

how to implement two queries within one MySQL statement?

for example coding

```
<?php var query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO adminDetails (user_name) VALUES ('uma');SELECT * FROM adminDetails");
?>
```

The above sql is giving result.but i used the same concept in below statement but it is not working

```
<?php
mysql_query("INSERT INTO adminDetails (user_name) VALUES ('uma');UPDATE domainname SET email='ragu@gmail.com' where id='18'") 
?>
```

Comment: why you want to using this?? split them with two different mysql_query

Comment: @Reka ARE YOU SURE you are getting the CORRECT RESULT? The function mysql_query does NOT allow multiple queries. You MUST run them separately. So please check that your results are correct. It cannot be.

Answer (score 2):

With `mysql_query` it can't be done, you have to use `mysqli's` [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) function for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with MySQLi `multi_query`

http://dev.fyicenter.com/faq/php/Query-Multiple-Tables-Jointly.html 
and
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php